# How to download game center?

Tags: ios, ipad, android

Game center does not appear in google play store. There's so many fake application with the same name. Please sending me a link to download it.

Comment: This one? [Game Center for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sencatech.key.gamecenter)

Comment: please edit this to link to an Apple product or add some details so an answer might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the Game Center app present in iOS : It's an app developed by Apple and it is only available on iOS (since version 4.1).